# linux 4.15.0-45- generic does not load, linux 4.15.0-44- generic works, ubuntu 18.04.1 LS

Tags: boot, kernel, dpkg

I am using ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS . After a resent update of the system, the option in the grub named
"ubuntu"
fails to load with a black screen output.
I have to got trough advanced options for ubuntu, where I find the following options:

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic (recovery mode)

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-44-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-44-generic (recovery mode)

testing, I found that Linux 4.15.0-45-generic is failing,  when running in recovery mode and choosing for example dpkg or fsck the following line appears:

/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory

option

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-44-generic

Is working fine.

Is there any way to fix the “Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic”?
How to define which kernel should be used in the first option “ubuntu” in the grub menu, so I don't have to travel trough “advanced options for ubuntu” and select the working kernel?

I have 3 machines, 2 of them have ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot along windows 10, the last machine has ubuntu 18.04 (also with the same dual boot along w10) and I have been experiencing a lot of issues with the latest. Machines with ubuntu 16.04 runs smoothly.

I appreciate your comments, guides and sugestions.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: The issue still persist. I just manage to change default kernel booting following this: [http://www.humans-enabled.com/2014/08/how-to-set-default-grub-kernel-boot.html]. This fix the issue of automatic booting in the failing kernel.

Comment: Did you manually install something like nvidia graphics or ati?

Comment: No. I have amd gpu installed properly. the issue came out after an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest one always boot first. If its corrupt or does not boot properly, you must remove it. Reboot after:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.15.0-45 linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
```

If it comes back via update manager, do the same or block it before updating.

See if it works after restart. Copy/paste any abnormal reading.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `amdgpu-pro` by any chance?
I got this working today by upgrading to `amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04`.

I was on `amdgpu-pro-18.50-708488-ubuntu-18.04` before, which did not work.

Comment: yes indeed. must try your advise